# Visual Studio 2010 - Only View Output of a Specific Category

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, output-window

In Visual Studio 2010, it would be beneficial to only view the output of a given debug category..

I.E.

```
Debug.WriteLine("debugging", "category1");
Debug.WriteLine("debugging2", "category2");
```

We have numerous developers developing on the same project and theres a lot going on in the output window that we dont need to see... if we could only view the debug info for "`category1`" for example, it would make things a lot easier.

Are there any VS 2010 extensions to handle this or is there a better way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this isn't possible (at least with the default setup of Visual Studio).